# Can I use database IP address instead of hostname in JDBC connector?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, database-connection

Currently none of my hostnames are resolving to my server which uses no-ip DDNS related to [this](https://www.noip.com/blog/2014/06/30/ips-formal-statement-microsoft-takedown/) issue. Is it possible to use the server IP address instead of the DDNS domain name in the `JDBC` connector?

```
private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", host = "jdbc://mysql:no-ip.hostname/", dbName = "databaseName", username = "username", password = "password";
Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(host + dbName, username, password);
```

Comment: Usage of IP address is valid as host. So long as they are not changing frequently, one can use them.

Comment: It’s completely up to the driver, in your case `mysql` to interpret the `String` you have given. So, usually you can use an IP address, but to be sure, consult your database’s manual…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work.  I've never used a JDBC driver that would not accept an IP address for the host.